# How implement SFINAE limited to few types, using template parameter pack

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I need enable std::string and int, but using a parameter pack.

```
template <typename... ParamType, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<ParamType..., std::string>::value || std::is_same<ParamType..., int>::value>::type>
static inline void Log(const ParamType & ... args)
{

}
```

but i have errors when call

```
Log("hello"s, "world"s); //syntax ERROR
```

Desired result

```
Log(4,3,"Hello"s); //OK
Log("Hello"s); //OK
Log(5); //OK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses a few C++17-ism (`std::void_t`). There are various implementations of them for earlier C++ standards floating everywhere, if needed:

```
template <typename ... ParamType,
      typename = std::void_t<std::enable_if_t
                 <std::is_same_v<ParamType, std::string> ||
                  std::is_same_v<ParamType, int>>...>>
static inline void Log(const ParamType & ... args)
{

}
```

Comment: std::void_t Simple spell but effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want `(is_string_or_int(param_0)) && (is_string_or_int(param_1)) && (is_string_or_int(param_2)) && ...`. This can be written with the fold expression:

```
typename std::enable_if<
    (true && ... && (
        std::is_same<ParamType, std::string>::value ||
        std::is_same<ParamType, int>::value
    ))
>::type
```

This only works with C++17 and above. For a C++11 friendly solution, you can go for struct specializations to iterate over the types:

```cpp
// true iff Testing is any of Required...
template<typename Testing, typename... Required>
struct one_match : std::false_type {};

template<typename Testing, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct one_match<Testing, First, Rest...> : std::bool_constant<std::is_same<Testing, First>::value || one_match<Testing, Rest...>::value> {};

// true iff all of TestingTypes... are in the tuple RequiredTypesTuple
template<typename RequiredTypesTuple, typename... TestingTypes>
struct all_match;

template<typename... RequiredTypes>
struct all_match<std::tuple<RequiredTypes...>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename... RequiredTypes, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct all_match<std::tuple<RequiredTypes...>, First, Rest...> : std::bool_constant<one_match<First, RequiredTypes...>::value && all_match<std::tuple<RequiredTypes...>, Rest...>::value> {};


template <typename... ParamType, typename enabler =
typename std::enable_if<
    all_match<std::tuple<std::string, int>, ParamType...>::value
>::type>
static inline void Log(const ParamType & ... args)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) using fold-expressions:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... ParamType>
static inline auto Log(const ParamType&... args)
    -> std::enable_if_t<((std::is_same_v<ParamType, std::string>
                       || std::is_same_v<ParamType, int>) && ...)>
{
}
```

However, if there's no alternative overload of `Log`, that could be used for parameters that do not satisfy the condition, consider using `static_assert` instead to provide an informative error message:

```
template <typename... ParamType>
static inline void Log(const ParamType&... args)
{
    static_assert(((std::is_same_v<ParamType, std::string>
                 || std::is_same_v<ParamType, int>) && ...)
                  , "Only ints and strings");
}
```

---

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) using concepts:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
concept LogParam = std::is_same_v<T, std::string> || std::is_same_v<T, int>;

static inline void Log(const LogParam auto&... args)
{
}
```